# Не работает resynthesizer в гимпе

Tags: ubuntu

стояли убунту 10.10 и 2.7, resynthesizer работал нормально, установил 12.04 и 2.8, resynthesizer установился, но не работает

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переустановить пакет:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gimp-resynthesizer
```

Если не поможет, то запустите Gimp с терминала, попробуйте использовать resynthesizer, скопируйте вывод с консоли и продемонстрируйте его нам. Таким образом мы получим информацию про ошибку и сможем помочь с ее устранением.

---

> запустил в терминале, отработалнеплохо, запустил как обычно, опятьерунда какая то, в терминале:victor@victor-eMachines-E627:~$ sudogimp [sudo] password for victor: dcraw-i '/home/victor/Изображения/011c.jpg' Cannot decode file/home/victor/Изображения/011c.jpgзапустил без su: GIMP-Ошибка: Unableto run plug-in "po"(/home/victor/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/po)Не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок«/home/victor/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/po»(Отказано в доступе)

Выполните команду:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte & alacarte
```

Тем самым Вы установите и откроете утилиту для редактирования главного меню. Найдите GIMP в списке элементов и добавьте в начало команды его запуска: "gksu". Например: " gimp-2.6 %U" необходимо изменить на "gksu  gimp-2.6 %U".

Теперь при каждом запуске GIMP у Вас будет запрашиваться пароль для активизации режима sudo.

Comment: запустил в терминале, отработал неплохо, запустил как обычно, опять ерунда какая то, в терминале: victor@victor-eMachines-E627:~$ sudo gimp[sudo] password for victor: dcraw -i '/home/victor/Изображения/011c.jpg'Cannot decode file /home/victor/Изображения/011c.jpg

Comment: запустил без su:GIMP-Ошибка: Unable to run plug-in "po"(/home/victor/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/po)Не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок «/home/victor/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/po» (Отказано в доступе)GIMP-Ошибка: Unable to run plug-in "src"(/home/victor/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/src)Не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок «/home/victor/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/src» (Отказано в доступе)Removing duplicate PDB procedure 'plug-in-resynthesizer' registered by '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/resynth'script-fu-pixel-stretch: image-type contains unrecognizable parts:'RBG

Comment: все работает!!!!))) спасибо!!!! был конфликт между гимп/плагинс и юзер/.... после удаления в гимп папки плагинс, все заработало отдельное спасибо Владимиру который не пожалел для меня времени (мин 30) приехал и сделал всё!!)))